# List Mapped Drives of All Users

Tags: windows-xp, script, windows-registry

I often have to replicate the mapping of drives of one machine to another. While I know how to easily output the data for the CURRENT user I have not found a way of doing this for others who are not currently logged on which for various reasons I need to be able to do.

I've tried in vain finding the data in the registry (once again I can find the mapped drives of the CURRENT user in HKCU\NETWORK but not for other users) and my searches on the internet haven't been too useful either so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In Hkey_USERS  all these wierd Id tag things **S-1-5-21-1017659469-3233765421-1457166851-500**  are the Users both current and non current.  there is a network folder in each of them. there is also CurrentControlSets and all the other usual stuff.

it is just a matter of finding the user TYPE Like 500 is admin, and a USER might be a 1000, like this  HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1272468093-1708547768-1957994088-1006

I have always seen all the users that are created in XP ? (or thought I did) But I dont really have users.  So if that doesnt work, then it would be loading in thier Hive or Hve , to work with it. which is different.

(the above IDs are munged, and not actual)

[Google search for how to Map network drives at log-in of users using scriipting](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=script+mapping+network+drives+at+log-in&pbx=1&oq=script+mapping+network+drives+at+log-in&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1260l17827l1l18078l50l26l9l15l19l0l228l3791l6.16.4l47l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1083cc5305162393&biw=1190&bih=890)

Comment: Those "weird id things" are Security Identifiers (SIDs). Using [`psgetsid`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897417) (form Sysinternal's PSTools) you can translate to/from user/group names. SIDs remain fixed when groups and users are renamed, hence references don't need to be updated.

Comment: Now you go getting all technical :-)  So your saying they are not going to change so Alen could import into them easily.  . . In Admin access will all the users show up in all situations?  In Win7 I am not seeing my alternate user?

Comment: SIDs are fixed. The set under HKEY_ALL_USERS is the set of users with local profiles (so that can change). Not sure what you mean by "in admin access [...]". Neither what you mean by alternate user.

Comment: I looked in the HKUSERS but did not find the NETWORK sub folder in them. Maybe I was forgetful enough not to check if the account had mapped drives to begin with so I'll let y'all know tomorrow when I can test it out. Also, thanks for pointing out psgetsid, I already use psexec and find it tremendously helpful.

Comment: if I enter the registry as admin, should I be able to see all users in all situations. My alternate user, my own second account, my backup account. I think i shoud jump back to xp, and look closer.

Comment: Tried it today guys and no luck, anything else to try perhaps?

Comment: Out of hundreds of IT type people who showed how to do this, most of them used the Scripting method at log-in/startup. I saw only one that added it direct to the registry itself. by loading user hives and edited them.  Being XP I would try and edit the registry, and use the Export-Alter-Import. I would have to see it there, then alter.  If that does not work, that leaves changing your question to how to Script the addition of Network mapped drives at user log-in.