# How can I view mapped network drives using a docking bay?

Tags: hard-drive, regedit, mapped-drive, net-use

I'm cloning drives using a hard drive docking bay, and I would like to see which drives a user had mapped on this machine before I pulled the HD out of it.

Is there a way to see mapped network drives on this drive? Regedit and the net use command give me drives on my own machine, but not on this externally connected hard drive.

Comment: SIMILAR to https://superuser.com/questions/343536/list-mapped-drives-of-all-users

Comment: You want to know who else has mapped a given drive? You have to query each user on each computer for this data.

Comment: @music2myear I have another user's hard drive that I am exploring using a docking bay hooked up to my workstation.  I'd like to see the mapped drives on the user's hard drive.

Comment: Drives mapped are not recorded on the target drive, but on the source computers.